# Sum column values and save at the database in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, swing, hibernate, jpa

I've searched for it everywhere but i couldn't able find a solution that solved my problem, i'm trying to sum all the inputs from the column with `JPQL` query and submit in a column called `total` and after the insertion display this result in a JTextField, i've tried it in different ways but no one gave alright. Here is my resolution:

```
public class ViewPedidos extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

private DAOManager manager;
private PedidoModel model;
private MySQLPedidoDAO mspdao;
private MySQLClienteDAO mscdao;
private MySQLProdutoDAO msprdao;
private List<Produto> produtos;
private List<Pedido> pedidos;
private Pedido ped;
private Produto pro;
private boolean editavel;


public void inserirDados(Pedido ped) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));

        { JTextField sets ...} 

        /*LINE GIVING THE ERROR UNDER!!! */
        //float soma = mspdao.retornaSoma();
        Double soma = mspdao.retornaSoma();
        ped.setTotal(soma);
    }  }
```

MySQLPedidoDAO class:

```
public class MySQLPedidoDAO implements PedidoDAO {

    public ConnectionFactory cf;


    public MySQLPedidoDAO(ConnectionFactory cf) {
        this.cf = cf;
    }

    /*
    @Override
    public float retornaSoma(){
       cf.createEm().getTransaction().begin();
       Query q = cf.createEm().createQuery("SELECT sum(valorTotal) from pedido");
       float soma = (float) q.getSingleResult();
       cf.createEm().getTransaction().commit();
       cf.close();
       return soma;
    }*/

    public Double retornaSoma(){
       cf.createEm().getTransaction().begin();
       Query q = cf.createEm().createQuery("SELECT sum(valorTotal) from pedido");
       Double soma = (float) q.getSingleResult();
       cf.createEm().getTransaction().commit();
       cf.close();
       return soma;
    }      }
```

Pedido class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pedido")
public class Pedido implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dataCadastro;
    @Column
    private String nomeProduto;
    @Column
    private int numControle;
    @Column
    private int quantidade;
    @Column(precision=15, scale=7)
    private float valorUnitario;
    @Column
    private Integer codCliente;
    @Column(precision=15, scale=7)
    private float valorTotal;
    @Column
    //private float total;
    private Double total;


    public Pedido() {
    }


    public Pedido(int numControle, Date dataCadastro, String nomeProduto, float valorUnitario, float valorTotal, int quantidade, int codCliente){
        this.numControle = numControle;
        this.dataCadastro = dataCadastro;
        this.nomeProduto = nomeProduto;
        this.valorUnitario = valorUnitario;
        this.valorTotal = valorTotal;
        this.quantidade = quantidade;
        this.codCliente = codCliente;
    }

    { getters and setters }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pedido" + "id=" + id + ", dataCadastro=" + dataCadastro + ", nomeProduto=" + nomeProduto + ", numControle=" + numControle + ", quantidade=" + quantidade + ", valorUnitario=" + valorUnitario + ", codCliente=" + codCliente + ", valorTotal=" + valorTotal + ", total=" + getTotal() + '\n';
    }

    /**
     * @return the total
     */
    public float getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    /**
     * @param total the total to set
     */
    public void setTotal(float total) {
        this.total = total;
    }  }
```

Testing it with Main class it gave me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: pedido is not mapped [SELECT sum(valorTotal) from pedido]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:331)
    at com.exemplo.repositorio.MySQLPedidoDAO.retornaSoma(MySQLPedidoDAO.java:115)
    at com.exemplo.main.Main.retornaSoma(Main.java:117)
    at com.exemplo.main.Main.main(Main.java:35)
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: pedido is not mapped [SELECT sum(valorTotal) from pedido]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1796)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: pedido is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:331)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3633)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3522)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:706)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:562)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
    ... 11 more
```

and Executing at the ViewPedidos form it gave me another StackTrace (after all, which object is missing on it??):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.exemplo.view.ViewPedidos.inserirDados(ViewPedidos.java:580)
    at com.exemplo.view.ViewPedidos.btInserirActionPerformed(ViewPedidos.java:406)
    at com.exemplo.view.ViewPedidos.access$400(ViewPedidos.java:46)
    at com.exemplo.view.ViewPedidos$5.actionPerformed(ViewPedidos.java:283)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I've already tried to declare the retornaSoma() function with List return and put it at the insert event, the function was performed but it didn't submitted.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNaYp.jpg)

Comment: 1) Please use **code formatting** (not  the formatting for an HTML/CSS/JS snippet available in the button two to the right) for code and code snippets, structured documents like XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the **`{}` button** at the top of the message posting/editing form. 2) Please [edit] the question to correct this.

Comment: Your entity is named Pedido, not pedido. Class names are case-sensitive in JPQL too.

Comment: @JBNizet I've put `Query q = cf.createEm().createQuery("SELECT sum(valorTotal) from Pedido");` and at the return in `Double`, in `float` it always gave cast error so i've decided to let `Double`. Now the only problem is that i can't able to get the value from this function and put it at the total variable but it didn't recording the value (i've modified my solution above after debug check it out)

Answer (score 0):

Now i've realized my error:

MySQLPedidoDAO:

```js
@Override
    public Double retornaSoma(){
       cf.createEm().getTransaction().begin();
       //Line corrected
       Query q = cf.createEm().createQuery("select sum(valorTotal) from Pedido");
       Double soma = (Double) q.getSingleResult();
       cf.createEm().getTransaction().commit();
       cf.close();
       return soma;
    }
```

Pedido:

```js
    /**
     * @return the total
     */
    //Instead float
    public Double getTotal() {
        return total;
    }


    public void setTotal(Double total) {
        this.total = total;
    }
```

Finally working! Thanks a lot!